# How to perform webscraping in Unity with tools similar to selenium, beautiful soup, and chromedriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, unity-game-engine, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to web scrape data in Unity. I am familiar with using selenium, beautiful soup, and chromedriver with Python to web scrape data outside of Unity. What similar tools and methods can I use within Unity in C# to web scrape data? UnityWebRequest from my understanding is mostly useful for getting information from other public API's with simple web requests. I'm looking for tools I can use to do more complicated web scraping within Unity. Would appreciate any help. Is there a way to control use chromedriver to control a chrome window through Unity? What is the best way to approach web scraping within Unity?